# How can i open up a simple page from my panorama app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a panorama app and made a button on one of the pages. How can open up a page when the user clicks the button?

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SearchPage sp = new SearchPage();
            sp.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
```

Now, the `sp.Visibility` seems to be the wrong way to go about it. Could anyone help me figuring out how I show secondary pages?

Comment: consider accept answers to your questions. So far you have done that to only %50 of cases. This will encourage people to answer your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like web applications, in your silverlight application you need to redirect the user to the next page.

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SearchPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
```

you can pass parameters to your page by adding query string parameters:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SearchPage.xaml?name=" + txtName.Text, UriKind.Relative);
```

and in `SearchPage.cs` you can retrieve the query string by saying this:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var name = NavigationContext.QueryString["name"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say a page, you mean a panoramaitem or a new page in your application?